# Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters” Leetcode Recursive Solution Doesn't Work

Tags: python, recursion

Gets accepted for all test cases unless the inputted string is too long. Why is this happening and can I make this solution recursively? Is this because python has recursion limits as a language (would this work in java?) or is there something else that's wrong?

```
class Solution:
    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s: str) -> int:
        if len(s) == 0:
            return 0
        if len(s) == 1:
            return 1
        start = 0
        index = 0
        length = len(s)
        list = []
        strr = ""
        listt = self.getSubstring(s,[],index,list,start,length)
        for i in listt:
            if len(i) > len(strr):
                strr = i
        print(len(strr))
        return len(strr)


    def getSubstring(self,s,keys,index,list,start,length):
        #print("s",s)
        #print("start",start)
        #print("index",index)
        #print("keys",keys)
        #print("list",list)
        if index == len(s)-1:
            if s[index] in keys:
                list.append(s[start:index])
                #print(list)
                return list
            else:
                list.append(s[start:index+1])
                #print(list)
                return list
        if s[index] in keys:
            list.append(s[start:index])
            return self.getSubstring(s,[],start+1,list,start+1,length)
        else:
            keys.append(s[index])
            return self.getSubstring(s,keys,index+1,list,start,length)
```

Comment: do you get any particular error message or something? hard to tell "what's wrong" unless you provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

This code solves this problem in linear time, the explanation at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/length-of-the-longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/ or you may check out https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/ which is approximately the same:

```
NO_OF_CHARS = 256

def longestUniqueSubsttr(string): 
    n = len(string) 
    cur_len = 1        # To store the length of current substring 
    max_len = 1        # To store the result 
    prev_index = 0    # To store the previous index 
    i = 0

    # Initialize the visited array as -1, -1 is used to indicate 
    # that character has not been visited yet. 
    visited = [-1] * NO_OF_CHARS 

    # Mark first character as visited by storing the index of 
    # first character in visited array. 
    visited[ord(string[0])] = 0

    # Start from the second character. First character is already 
    # processed (cur_len and max_len are initialized as 1, and 
    # visited[str[0]] is set 
    for i in xrange(1, n): 
        prev_index = visited[ord(string[i])] 

        # If the currentt character is not present in the already 
        # processed substring or it is not part of the current NRCS, 
        # then do cur_len++ 
        if prev_index == -1 or (i - cur_len > prev_index): 
            cur_len+= 1

        # If the current character is present in currently considered 
        # NRCS, then update NRCS to start from the next character of 
        # previous instance. 
        else: 
            # Also, when we are changing the NRCS, we should also 
            # check whether length of the previous NRCS was greater 
            # than max_len or not. 
            if cur_len > max_len: 
                max_len = cur_len 

            cur_len = i - prev_index 

        # update the index of current character 
        visited[ord(string[i])] = i 

    # Compare the length of last NRCS with max_len and update 
    # max_len if needed 
    if cur_len > max_len: 
        max_len = cur_len 

    return max_len 

# Driver program to test the above function 
string = "ABDEFGABEF"
print "The input string is " + string 
length = longestUniqueSubsttr(string) 
print ("The length of the longest non-repeating character" +
       " substring is " + str(length))
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive implementation would be like so in pseudocode:

```py
function lengthOfLongestSubstring(s)
    for each c in s
        unique[c] = false

    n = s.length()
    max_len = 0
    for i in range(0, n):
        max_len = max(max_len, max_sub_str(s, i)
    return max_len

function max_sub_str(s, i)
    if (i >= s.length() || unique[s[i]]) return 0;
    unique[s[i]] = 1;
    int count = 1 + max_sub_str(s, i + 1);
    unique[s[i]] = 0;
        
    return count;
```